# Botão para inserir registos na Base de Dados

Tags: c#, sql, .net, visual-studio

Boas, estou a realizar um projeto para a minha PAP que consiste na criação de uma BD para uma empresa. No entanto, decidi colocar um botão para adicionar registos e quando clico para adicionar, aparece o seguinte erro: Falha ao converter o valor do parâmetro de DataTimePicker para DateTime
Que posso eu fazer? Deixo-vos a seguinte imagem que contém e a imagem do erro e mando por aqui o código:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into Utilizador(IDuser, Nome, Localidade, DataDeNascimento, Idade, Email, Login, Senha, Telefone, TelefoneEE, Perfil, Imagem) 
                      values (@IDuser, @Nome, @Localidade, @DatadeNascimento, @Idade, @Email, @Login, @Senha, @Telefone, @TelefoneEE, @Perfil, @Imagem", sql);
                command.Parameters.Add("@IDuser", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = iDuserTextBox.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Nome", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nomeTextBox.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Localidade", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = localidadeTextBox.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@DataDeNascimento", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dataDeNascimentoDateTimePicker;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Idade", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = idadeTextBox.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = emailTextBox.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Login", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = loginTextBox.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Senha", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = senhaTextBox.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Telefone", SqlDbType.Char).Value = telefoneTextBox.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@TelefoneEE", SqlDbType.Char).Value = telefoneEETextBox.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Imagem", SqlDbType.Image).Value = imagemPictureBox.Image;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Perfil", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = perfilTextBox.Text;
```

Obrigado por a ajuda. Abraço

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mude a linha:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@DataDeNascimento", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dataDeNascimentoDateTimePicker;
```

Para:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@DataDeNascimento", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dataDeNascimentoDateTimePicker.Value;
```

Comment: Boas,
Fiz o que sugeriste e apareceu-me outro erro... deste vez como: Falha ao converter o valor do parâmetro de Bitmap para Byte[].
Suponho que seja da Imagem não?

Comment: Sim, é preciso verificar qual é o tipo de retorno de "imagemPictureBox.Image" e convertê-lo para o valor adequado da coluno do teu BD.

Comment: Desculpa a minha ignorância, mas eu sou um principiante em programação ainda... Como é que realizo isso que explicaste?